# How to Embed KML files (Google Earth) into a website without the google gadget?

Tags: kml

I am trying to embed a KML file onto our webpage and the way it was previously done, using the KML embedding tool from Google no longer works, it seems that google has taken the gadget down or something.  Is there another way of doing this that isn't overly complex? Any Suggestions and or advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: load the kml into fusion tables - that is what has changed  http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171181?hl=en#kml

Comment: Thank you for the information unfortunately it wont work for the information and data we want to display

Comment: Can you be more specific, heather, why isn't google fusion tables working? Another option that is a bit more serious than Google Fusion tables is Google Map Engine https://mapsengine.google.com/map/?pli=1

Comment: The files that I have to process are too large and too complex, or im missing something which is possible, I will defintely look into the map engine

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the "KML embedding tool from Google" did.

However, if you want to display your KML on top of a basemap (Google Maps or another one like OpenStreetMap), you can use a library like Leaflet ([KML plugin](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins)) or OpenLayers ([KML display example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html)).

Comment: the tool embedded a copy of google earth into the coding of the website, and unfortunately the basemap of google is too simple for the data that we're trying to display, we need the satelite imagery of google earth or something similar, Thanks for the Suggestion though

Comment: You can display your KML on top of Google satellite imagery with OpenLayers or with Leaflet

Answer (score 1):

If you have a google account, you can store the kml as a file in google drive. Then it will natively display from there onto a Google map. 
However this is for relatively simple kmls, without too many features and without background images.

It may then be a simple matter to have a link from your webpage to the url of the kml. You would share the kml from Google Drive to "anyone with the link".

Let us know how you go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the files that we have are quite large and complex, so this option wont work for us, we're trying to display surveying data from a survey that we completed of an area's drainage infrastructure and we're trying to make the data easily accessable for our board members and our public.

Comment: Hi Willy, I am trying to do just what u describe. Here is what I have done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060123/how-to-create-a-kml-map-overlay

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resurrect the code from the gadget, and get it working again:

http://www.nearby.org.uk/blog/2014/09/16/resurrecting-the-google-kml-embed-and-tour-gadgets/

Answer (score 0):

GPX, KML, SHP (ESRI shapefile), or OSM XML format can be loaded as a basemap with Potlatch_2, according to this wiki page

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Potlatch_2/vector_background_layers

Potlatch:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potlatch_%28software%29

Answer (score 0):

The free level of CartoDB could easily handle what you're trying to do- very powerful and simple to use so far. Leaflet or the new MapBox.js tools are powerful but more work to learn over basic CartoDB. Simple MapBox hosted maps could work for you too- they are fun to play with! Otherwise try geocommons for a hosted but feature rich option for less developer types- but be warned it is also slow for large files to display..

what is the info you want to display that doesn't work in Fusion tables? they can do a lot easily too.

good luck
Spike

Comment: I am still looking for a slightly better tool but for now GeoCommons worked for me, it can be quite slow but the files that Im working with are quite large, we're wanting to display a bunch of culvert\drainage infrastructure survey data, it's quite hard converting it for the fusion tables unless I'm doing it wrong which is totally possible.  Thank you for the suggestions